# Compile-time configuration across several c++ projects

Tags: c++, c, configuration

I need a compile-time project configuration file which configures several c++ projects.
My setting is this:

- I have three C++ projects, one of them a static library: proj1, proj2, lib1
- Both proj1 and proj2 use lib1
- proj1 and proj2 compile to executables running on different Arduino boards
- All three projects need values for configuration variables (e.h. UDP port to use, debug level, etc.)
- proj1 and proj2 are actually very similiar and share many configuration variables
- proj1 and proj2 need differing configuration values, also for lib1

I need a simple solution to configure all three.
I need it to be low on resource usage, as I am memory-constrained (deployed on Arduino).

---

My first solution was a configuration.h file in each project, containing #define's for the respective project.

Problem with this approach: I cannot define differing values for lib1 from proj1/proj2. Say, lib1 defines UDP_PORT, then I cannot specify a different UDP_PORT in proj1/proj2 which lib1 will actually use.

---

Of course I could pass all these configuration values as parameters at run-time. To save memory and runtime, I would prefer a compile time solution however.

Comment: Aside of your problem, it is probably a very bad idea to hardcode a udp port into your program...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things you can do:

1. When compiling pass the defines from the command line and compile a separate version of the lib for each project

   > gcc -DUDP_PORT=1234 myProject.cpp
   >
   > gcc -DUDP_PORT=1234 myLib.cpp
2. Pass the hard-coded UDP port from the project to the lib at runtime. This really is not going to impact your overhead.

   ```
   // in project_1
   lib::set_udp_port(UDP_PORT);

   // in the lib
   static short g_udp_port;

   lib::set_udp_port(short port)
   {
       g_udp_port = port;
   }
   ```
3. Number 2, but pass the port in on the command-line when running the program

   > my_program --port 1234

Comment: Thanks for the good overview. I will probably go with option 1 in combination with a makefile, which allows me to store all config values in a friendly file.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class *ConfigurationParameterVault*, with an interface suitable to provide all the parameters you need. Put the .h file in a place where all the projects has access to it (maybe in the lib's project?)

Common.h

```
class ConfigurationParameterVault{
    ConfigurationParameterVault();
    ~ConfigurationParameterVault();
public:
    int getUDPPort();
    int getOtherParameter();
    ...

    void* m_pImpl;
}
```

Now add a .cpp file (where too implement the vault) for each project. So at building time the liker choses the implementation from .cpp file in the project it is building!

The implementation of the vault follows the PIMPL idiom.. So every implementation may store some state in the vault also if the header file is common.

In the first project: Vault.cpp

```
class Project1VaultImpl{

     Project1VaultImpl() :
          udpPort(53124),
          otherParam(28){


     };

     int udpPort;
     int otherParam;
}

ConfigurationParameterVault::ConfigurationParameterVault() :
         m_pImpl(new Project1VaultImpl()){
}

ConfigurationParameterVault::ConfigurationParameterVault() :
     delete m_pImpl;
}

int ConfigurationParameterVault::getUDPPort(){
    Project1VaultImpl* pImpl = reinterpret_cast<Project1VaultImpl*>(m_pImpl);

    return pImpl->udpPort;
}
```

If all the project needs to share some common parameters, all the Pimpls may extend the same base class. If one project need to use a value that is different from the common one, its particular implementation of the vault can override it

Comment: While this would work, it does consume RAM. I have only 2k of it :-(

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether your Arduino build system was hosted on Windows, Linux or "something else".

Whichever: you should easily be able to automate building one or more projects using "make":

http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Learning/CommandLine

https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-cmake

If you're unfamiliar with "make", there are many good tutorials on the web, including this:

http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

Comment: make is a good pointer. I would use -D flag to set the #define's. Or something like AC_CONFIG_HEADERS from the automake tools. Will look into it.